# SQL searchable cache - high scalability

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, caching, optimization

I have developed a website which provides very generic data storage. Currently it works just fine but I am thinking about optimizing the speed.

INSERT/SELECT ratio is hard to predict and changes for different cases but usually SELECT is more often. INSERTs are fast enough. SELECTs are what worries me. There are a lot of LEFT JOINs. E.g. each object can have a image which is stored in separate table (as it can span across multiple objects) and stores additional information about the image as well.

Up to 8 joins are made every select and it can take up to 1 seconds to process - mean value is around 0.3s. There can be multiple of such selects for every request. It has already been optimized multiple times on SQL side and there is not much that can be done there.

Other than buying more powerful machine for DB, what can be done (if anything)?

Django is not a speed demon here as well but we still got some optimizations left there. Switch to PyPy if we must. On DB side I had a few ideas but there they seem to be uncommon - couldn't find any real case scenario.

- Use different storage for this part that's faster. We need transactions and we need consistency checks so it may not be preferable.
- Searchable cache? Does it make any sense here? E.g. maintain a flat copy of all tables combined in NoSQL or something. Inserts would be more expensive - it needs to update multiple records in NoSQL if some common table changes. Tough to maintain as well.

Is there anything that would make sense or is it just the fastest that can get and just get more RAM, increase cache size in rdbms, get SSD and leave it. Focus on optimizing other parts like pooling database connections as they are expensive as well.

Technologies used: PostgreSQL 9.1 and Django (python).

To summarize. Question is: after optimizing all SQL part - indexes, clustering etc. What can be done to optimize further when static timeout cache for results is not an option (different request arguments, different results anyway).

---**EDIT** 30-08-2012---

We are already using checking slow queries on a daily basis. This IS our bottleneck. We only order and filter on indexes. Also, sorry for not being clear about this - we don't store actual images in db. Just file paths.

JOINs and ORDER BY are killing our performance here. E.g. one complex query that spits out 20 000 results takes 1800ms (EXPLAIN ANALYZE used). And this assumes that we are not using any kind of filtering based on JOINed tables.

If we skip all the JOINS we are down to 110ms. That's insane... That's why we are thinking of some kind of searchable cache or flat copy NoSQL.

Without ordering we got 60ms which is great but what's with the JOIN performance in PostgreSQL?
Is there some different DB that can do better for us? Preferably free one.

Comment: find (and fix) your actual bottleneck springs to mind

Comment: The usual answer would be memcached, but you've ruled that out. If you can't cache, then you need to make your DB faster or improve your access patterns to reduce round trips, batch work, etc.

Comment: At least show some queries and their `explain analyze`. People can't help with SQL performance without even looking at the SQL. If you end up with complex queries that truly can't run quickly but need the response time of simple queries, going for [materialized views](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Materialized_Views) may help a lot.

Comment: I wasn't asking about optimizing SQL. I was asking if there is anything to be done other than buying new machine when SQL is already optimized. You're link is useful and is a closest thing to an answer right now. I haven't heard materialized views - will definitely check this out! Thanks!

Comment: Just because you think your queries are optimized doesn't mean they are.  Feel free to toss a query and it's explain analyze output on here via http://explain.depesz.com/ here for us to look at.  It may well be something a pg expert looks at and has a whole different idea on how to fix.  Also, how many tables are you joining?  What's your data definition of those tables look like?

Answer (score 3):

First, although I think that there are times and places to store image files in the database, in general you are going to have extra I/O and memory associated with this sort of operation.  If I was looking at optimizing this I would put every image with a path and be able to bulk save these to the fs.  This way they are still in your db for backup purposes but you can just pull the relative path out and generate links, thus saving you a bunch of sql queries and reducing overhead.  Over a web-based backend you aren't going to be able to get transactions working really well between generating the HTML and retrieving the image anyway since these come in under different HTTP requests.

As for speed, I can't tell if you are looking at total http request time or db time.  But the first thing you need to do is break everything apart and look for where most of your time is being spent.  This may surprise you.  The next thing is to get query plans of those queries which are slow queries:

http://heatware.net/databases/how-to-find-log-slow-queries-postgresql/

Then from there, start using explain analyze to find out what is the problem.

Also in deciding to upgrade hardware you want to have a good idea of where you are currently facing limits.  More RAM helps generally (and it is helpful if your db can fit comfortably in RAM), but beyond that it makes no sense to put faster storage in a cpu-bound server or switch to a server with faster cpu's in an I/O bound server.  top is your friend there.  Similarly depending on the concurrency issues, it might (or might not!) make sense to use a hot standby for your select statements.

But without a lot more information I can't tell you what the best way to go about further optimizing your db is.  PostgreSQL is capable of running really fast under the right conditions and scaling very well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I edited my original question and added more info so it should cover your answer already.